# Using vagrant ssh to edit mysql config on Windows

Tags: vagrant, homestead

How I can change my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and add `sql-mode="allow_invalid_dates"` in n y `vagrant ssh` command after connecting?

I tried to run `vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf` which opens the file, but not option to save it after editing..

Answer (score 1):

You can run a vagrant [shell provisioner](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html)

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo 'sql-mode=\"allow_invalid_dates\"' >> /etc/sysconfig/configfile"
  ...
end
```

This will run it automatically for you

If you want to do from the vm and edit the file yourself, make sure you do as sudo and from `vi` do the following:

- type ":$" to get to the end of the file
- type ":i" to get into insert mode
- type want you want, when you're done  type ESC
- type ":wq" to write and quit

I'm sure you can find plenty of tutorial on vi